# What is a triple integral with the answer of 39?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

What is a triple integral with the answer of 39

Comment: The simplest would presumably be to integrate constant 1 over a rectangular prism of volume 39.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 8):

$$39\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 dxdzdy$$

Comment: Why would you answer _that_? Have some self-respect.

Comment: @Yes I was hoping my snarkiness came through. Apparently not. Any edits to emphasize that are appreciated. :)

Comment: @avid19 You could take the 39 outside the integrals, for one :)

Comment: I am sorry, but your solution is a definite triple integral. The OP is looking for an indefinite triple integral.